# how to take single field value when use the ',' in field value in csv file

Tags: apex, batch, csv, aggregate

```
for(sObject sObj : scope) {
            AggregateResult ar = (AggregateResult)sObj;
            Integer IdCount = (Integer)ar.get('cnt');
            String accName = (String)ar.get('accName');

            if(String.isNotBlank(accName)){
                csvRow = accName + ','+ IdCount;
                listContactDetail.add(csvRow);
            }          
        }
```

here is the code where I create the CSV File
Here the problem is when the CSV file is created the field value of accName use the comma(,) like (sunny,roxx) then the created CSV file columns are not assiged[image]

here you see in the image 'mortgage & investment agenct' comes to other columns
please give me a suggestion for solved this error
thanks in advance

Comment: As explained in [how to escape comma in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092871/7407067) your string should be enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: Can you please give the answer of this question how to resolve, I will mark your answer is best answer

Comment: Can you please give the answer to this example of how to resolve it, I will mark your answer as the best answer thanks.

Comment: The answer provided to you does not escape characters properly. You will experience errors in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing you need to do is update the line where you assign the value to `csvRow` as follow:

```
csvRow = '"' + accName + '",'+ IdCount;
```

you only need to concatenate `"` before variable `accName` and also after it.
hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for giving your valuable time.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle quotation characters in the string. `The "Famous" Dave's` would break the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You should use escapeCSV to make sure that you're dealing with CSV characters correctly.

```
csvRow = accName.escapeCsv() + ','+ IdCount;
```